# Oracle APEX - How do you specify the Database Edition to connect to at login

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am developing an Oracle APEX application against a database which uses Oracle Editions (Edition Based Redefinition).

My APEX application will be using Database Account Authentication - how can I direct the Database Edition that Sessions should be established against at login ?

Comment: As I understand it, database edition is an attribute of the APEX application itself. There doesn't seem to be a lot written about APEX and EBR, but this may help: https://www.doag.org/formes/pubfiles/9053218/2017-APEX-Bryn_Llewellyn-Upgrade_your_APEX_app_with_zero_downtime_by_using_EBR-Praesentation.pdf

Comment: That's great - thank you very much for pointer. I also found out, from https://blog.dbi-services.com/apex-connect-2017-day-3/, that there is an **APEX_UTIL.SET_EDITION** procedure to work with also.